# Change velocity based on a touch in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch

I have the following Bird, I want when the player touch a point on a screen to apply velocity on the Bird and move it to that point.

[image]

So I wrote the following:

```
 if (Input.touches.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach(Touch touch in Input.touches ){

                Vector2 pos = touch.deltaPosition;
                rigidbody2D.velocity = pos;

            }

        }
```

The problem is that this is executed only when there is something like a move of a finger on the screen and not something like a hit or tap. Any idea how can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should not modify the velocity directly. This can result in unrealistic behavior. I would recommend you to use rigidbody.AddForce( direction : Vector3 ). Add your functionality inside an Update Loop and use a break; to leave the foreach if you want that the force is added only once and not for every single finger on the display.